# Installing Numpy and Scipy - Can't find system python 2.6

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy, python-2.6

I"m trying to install numpy and scipy for a data analysis class I have this semester. I'm trying to install it from the package on sourceforge.net, but as I follow the wizard I can't select my HD. There is a message saying numpy.1.5.1 requires System Python 2.6. I know it is there as when I type `$ python` version 2.6.1 comes up.

I've done a bit of snooping under the hood and it looks like python 2.6 is under `usr/bin` where as python3 is in `usr/local/bin`.  I'm a bit new with the terminal so I'm not sure if I can throw the files in the `local/bin`, or if this is even the issue.

Thanks in advance

Operating System: OS X 10.6.6

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I've edited the post to include that.

Comment: Does binaries from http://www.scipy.org/Download work for you? Have you tried Scipy Superpack http://stronginference.com/scipy-superpack/ ?

Comment: Have you tried ActivePython/PyPM? http://code.activestate.com/pypm/scipy/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official [Numpy 1.5.1 installer for Python 2.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.5.1/) for OS X appear to require the [python.org Python 2.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/), not the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.

Comment: +1 just so I can give you 10000 rep. If I had 9999 rep, I would be going crazy.